# How can i insert an add instruction in IR file llvm?

Tags: llvm

I want to insert an add instruction in LLVM IR format, something like `x = x + 1`, where x is global variable. I have tried this:

```
GlobalVariable* x = new GlobalVariable(mod,Type::getInt32Ty(Context),false,GlobalValue::CommonLinkage,0,"xCounter");

Value one =  ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context),1);
newInst = BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::Add, , one ,"counter", insertPos);
```

But an error occurs, it does not accept type `GlobalVariable`.

How can I define a global variable and set its value?

Comment: Your last line - how to print it - is really its own question. I removed it from this question, you should ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are always pointers - in your case, its type will be `i32*`. You need to `load` from it first before you can `add` it with anything. You'll then have to `store` the new value, using the global variable as the store address.

It's the same with local variables, by the way - `alloca` values are always pointers.

Comment: Why i need to load the global variable from memory before using it, in my case , the initial value is constant number zero, and how can i use it in add instruction ?

Comment: @user3411138 when you have a pointer - and as I've written, global variables are always pointers - then you need to load the value from them first before you can use it.